# How to obtain better speed performance with NMinimize over a complicated objective function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, compile

**Edit.1:**

*I've rewritten the question in order to make it more accessible for troubleshooting / debugging / maintenance purposes, as suggested in the comments. I apologize for any inconvenience.*

**I'm trying to find the best way to write the objective function so as to minimize the time it takes `NMinimize` to solve my constraint minimization problem.**

The particulars of the problem are presented below.

I have tried defining the objective function using *three* different ways which I originally thought that would produce progressively better time gains. Unfortunately, I was mistaken.

The first two definitions use `SetDelayed` and `Function` while the last one uses a combination of `Function` and `Compile`.

Quoting from the original question:

> **How can I improve on either of the three versions or how to adopt a whole different approach in order to obtain sensible timing for the optimization problem at hand?**
>   *Eg*: using the first approach (simple definition-`SetDelayed`-for the objective function) with 100 observations and 48 variables was a 6.5 *min* long evaluation (using `AbsoluteTiming`) on a run. I'd hope to achieve half the time for double the variables if at all possible, but I'd settle for any changes that point towards an improving performance.

---

In what follows, I initialize the problem instance and then present the three different versions of the objective function used, along with the results obtained.

This initializes the problem instance:

```
vs = 4;
nObs = 100;
xs = makeVars["x", vs];
ys = makeVars["y", vs];
args = Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ Join[xs, ys];
vars = Join[xs, ys];

{data, parameters} = makeData[nObs, vs];
fAux = Variance[fAuxObjective[xs, ys, #] & /@ data];

constraints = makeConstraints[xs, ys, parameters];
init = initVariables[xs, ys, ConstantArray[1/vs, vs], parameters];
```

As an example, I'm using *two* sets of 4 variables each ie 8 variables in total and 100 observations. The number of observations and total variables used affect the number of terms in the objective function.

The formula for the objective function is contained in `fAux`.

Below are presented the three different cases I have already tried:

**Case 1:**

```
(* case 1. objective function defined with SetDelayed *)

Clear[fObjective]
Evaluate[Apply[fObjective][args]] := Evaluate[fAux]

fcons = Join[{Apply[fObjective][vars]}, constraints];
NMinimize[fcons, init]
```

> ```
> {0.0989053, {x1 -> 0.244909, x2 -> 0.311147, x3 -> 0.260978, x4 -> 0.182966, 
> y1 -> 0.248345, y2 -> 0.662958, y3 -> -0.485397, y4 -> 0.130779}}
> ```

**Case 2:**

```
(* case 2. objective function defined with Function and Set *)

Clear[fObjective]
fObjective = Function[Evaluate[vars], Evaluate[fAux]];

fcons = Join[{Apply[fObjective][vars]}, constraints];
NMinimize[fcons, init]
```

> ```
> {0.0989053, {x1 -> 0.244909, x2 -> 0.311147, x3 -> 0.260978, x4 -> 0.182966, 
> y1 -> 0.248345, y2 -> 0.662958, y3 -> -0.485397, y4 -> 0.130779}}
> ```

**Case 3:**

```
(* case 3. objective function defined with Compile and Set *)

Clear[fObjective]
copts = {CompilationTarget -> "C"};
gAux = Function[Evaluate[vars], Evaluate[fAux]];
fComp = Compile[{{args, _Real, 1}}, Apply[gAux][args], {{_, _Real}}, Evaluate[copts]];
fObjective[args_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := fComp[args];

fcons = Join[{fObjective[vars]}, constraints];
NMinimize[fcons, init]
```

> ```
> {0.0989053, {x1 -> 0.244909, x2 -> 0.311147, x3 -> 0.260978, x4 -> 0.182966, 
>  y1 -> -1., y2 -> 0.0161671, y3 -> -0.0143411, y4 -> 0.187533}}
> ```

In what follows are auxiliary definitions used in the generation of the objective function and the constraints.

```
(* create symbols to use as 'variables' *)
(* takes as input the string of the symbol to use and the number of symbols needed 
   and outputs appropriately numbered symbols *)
(* eg. evaluating makeVars["x", 3] outputs {x1, x2, x3} *)
makeVars[symbolString_, nVariables_] := Table[
  ToExpression[StringJoin[symbolString, ToString[i]]], {i, 1, nVariables}];


(* generate appropriate data points used in the objective function *)
(* takes as input the number of observation points (rows) to generate per variable, 
   the number of variables needed (columns) and a seed for random number generation *)
(* it outputs a list containing a matrix 'nObservations' x 'nVariables' and 
   a list 'nVariables' long *)
makeData[nObservations_, nVariables_, seed_: 2145879] := BlockRandom[
  {RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {nObservations, nVariables}], 
    RandomReal[{0, 1}, nVariables]}, RandomSeeding -> seed]


(* auxiliary function used in the construction of the objective function *)
(* takes as arguments three equally long lists; the former two are lists of 
   symbols (variables) and the later is a list of values (observations) *)
(* outputs a list (vector) of values )*)
(* eg fAuxObjective[{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}, {-0.1, 0.325}] 
   outputs -0.1 x1 - x1 y1 + 0.325 x2 - x2 y2 *)
fAuxObjective = Total[#1 #3 - #1 #2 ] &;


(* generate constraints *)
makeConstraints[variables1_, variables2_, 
  hiBounds2_, lowBounds2_: - 1., hiBounds1_: 1.] := Join[
    {Plus @@ variables1 == 1.},
    Thread[lowBounds2 <= variables2 <= hiBounds2],
    Thread[0. <= variables1 <= hiBounds1]
 ]


(* init variables *)
initVariables[variables1_, variables2_, initValues1_, initValues2_, 
  factor_: 0.01] := MapAt[
    Apply[Sequence][{# (1 - factor), # (1 + factor)}] &,
      Join[Transpose[{variables1, initValues1}], 
        Transpose[{variables2, initValues2}]], {All, 2}]
```

---

**Original Q:**

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem of modest size and I'm having trouble saving time by modifying the objective function.

The first attempt uses an objective function defined with a simple `SetDelayed`:

```
f = Total[vars[[1]] # - Times @@ vars] &;
BlockRandom[
  With[{data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, vs}], params = RandomReal[{0, 1}, vs]},
    With[{fval = Variance[f /@ data]},
      (* objective function *)
      objf[args__] := Evaluate[fval];
     ];
   ], RandomSeeding -> seed]
```

Please note that the objective function is dependent on a set of input data and other numeric parameters (I'm using random numbers to simulate them).

The second attempt follows more or less the same path but uses a `Function` instead:

```
BlockRandom[
  With[{data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, vs}], params = RandomReal[{0, 1}, vs]},
    With[{fval = Variance[f /@ data]},
      cf = Function[Evaluate[Flatten@vars], fval]
     ];
    objf[args__] := cf[args];
   ], RandomSeeding -> seed]
```

The third attempt uses `Compile` to define the objective function:

```
BlockRandom[
  With[{data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, vs}], params = RandomReal[{0, 1}, vs]},
    With[{fval = Variance[f /@ data]},
      With[{g = Function[Evaluate[Flatten@vars], fval]},
        cf = Compile[{{args, _Real, 1}}, Apply[g][args], {{_, _Real}}, Evaluate[copts]]
       ]
     ];
    objf[args_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := cf[args];
   ], RandomSeeding -> seed]
```

Please note the third argument in `Compile` without which *Mathematica* complains with `CompiledFunction::cfte` and `CompiledFunction::cfexe`.

After (limited) fooling around with the code provided in the end of this question, it seems that the *first* version is roughly equivalent to the *second* one (the second is marginally faster than the first) while the third is *way* slower than the first one (by a factor of 8x approx.).

And here is the problem: I was expecting a progressive improvement in evaluation speed between the three versions, which fails to obtain; especially so, after the unexpected slowdown from the version using `Compile`.

**How can I improve on either of the three versions or how to adopt a whole different approach in order to obtain sensible timing for the optimization problem at hand** (*please see code blocks at the end of this question*)**?**

*Eg*: using the first approach (simple definition-`SetDelayed`-for the objective function) with 100 observations and 48 variables was a 6.5 *min* long evaluation (using `AbsoluteTiming`) on a run. I'd hope to achieve half the time for double the variables if at all possible, but I'd settle for any changes that point towards an improving performance.

---

**Block 1**

```
Block[{makeVars, f, objf},

  (* no. of variables, symbols to use, observations (used in 'data' - see below) *)
  With[{vs = 4, syms = {"x", "y"}, n = 100, seed = 3254780},
    (* creates variables' symbols *)
    makeVars = Table[ToExpression[StringJoin[#1, ToString[i]]], {i, 1, vs}] &;

    With[{vars = makeVars /@ syms},

      (* 'f' depends on input data *)
      f = Total[vars[[1]] # - Times @@ vars] &;

      (* using random numbers in place of data and parameters *)
      BlockRandom[
        With[{data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, vs}], params = RandomReal[{0, 1}, vs]},

          (* 'fval' is the objective function *)
          With[{fval = Variance[f /@ data]},
            (* use a definition *)  
            objf[args__] := Evaluate[fval];
           ];

          (* add constraints and minimize *)
          With[{csts = {Total[vars[[1]]] == 1., Thread[0. <= vars[[1]] <= 1.], Thread[-1. <= vars[[-1]] <= params]}, d = 0.01, init = Transpose[{Flatten[vars], Join[ConstantArray[1/vs, vs], params]}]},
            NMinimize[Join[{Apply[objf][Flatten@vars]}, Flatten@csts], MapAt[Apply[Sequence][{# (1 - d), # (1 + d)}] &, init, {All, 2}]] // AbsoluteTiming
           ]
         ], RandomSeeding -> seed]
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

**Block 2**

```
Block[{makeVars, f, cf, objf},

  (* no. of variables, symbols to use, observations (used in 'data' - see below) *)
  With[{vs = 4, syms = {"x", "y"}, n = 100, seed = 3254780},
    (* creates variables' symbols *)
    makeVars = Table[ToExpression[StringJoin[#1, ToString[i]]], {i, 1, vs}] &;

    With[{vars = makeVars /@ syms},

      (* 'f' depends on input data *)
      f = Total[vars[[1]] # - Times @@ vars] &;

      (* using random numbers in place of data and parameters *)
      BlockRandom[
        With[{data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, vs}], params = RandomReal[{0, 1}, vs]},

          (* 'fval' is the objective function *)
          With[{fval = Variance[f /@ data]},
            (* enclose it in a function *)  
            cf = Function[Evaluate[Flatten@vars], fval];
           ];
          objf[args__] := cf[args];

          (* add constraints and minimize *)
          With[{csts = {Total[vars[[1]]] == 1., Thread[0. <= vars[[1]] <= 1.], Thread[-1. <= vars[[-1]] <= params]}, d = 0.01, init = Transpose[{Flatten[vars], Join[ConstantArray[1/vs, vs], params]}]},
            NMinimize[Join[{Apply[objf][Flatten@vars]}, Flatten@csts], MapAt[Apply[Sequence][{# (1 - d), # (1 + d)}] &, init, {All, 2}]] // AbsoluteTiming
           ]
         ], RandomSeeding -> seed]
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

**Block 3**

```
Block[{makeVars, f, cf, objf},

  (* no. of variables, symbols to use, observations (used in 'data' - see below) *)
  With[{vs = 4, syms = {"x", "y"}, n = 100, seed = 3254780},
    (* creates variables' symbols *)
    makeVars = Table[ToExpression[StringJoin[#1, ToString[i]]], {i, 1, vs}] &;

    With[{vars = makeVars /@ syms},

      (* 'f' depends on input data *)
      f = Total[vars[[1]] # - Times @@ vars] &;

      (* using random numbers in place of data and parameters *)
      BlockRandom[
        With[{data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, vs}], params = RandomReal[{0, 1}, vs]},

          (* 'fval' is the objective function *)
          With[{fval = Variance[f /@ data]},
            (* enclose it in a function *)  
            cf = Compile[{{args, _Real, 1}}, Apply[g][args], {{_,_Real}}, Evaluate[copts]];
           ];
          objf[args_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := cf[args];

          (* add constraints and minimize *)
          With[{csts = {Total[vars[[1]]] == 1., Thread[0. <= vars[[1]] <= 1.], Thread[-1. <= vars[[-1]] <= params]}, d = 0.01, init = Transpose[{Flatten[vars], Join[ConstantArray[1/vs, vs], params]}]},
            NMinimize[Join[{objf[Flatten@vars]}, Flatten@csts], MapAt[Apply[Sequence][{# (1 - d), # (1 + d)}] &, init, {All, 2}]] // AbsoluteTiming
           ]
         ], RandomSeeding -> seed]
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: If you really need help, how about unfolding your code a bit? These nested `With`s, `Block` and `BlockRandom`s are really annoying. This is not the way to write debuggable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should give you about a factor of 5:

```
Clear[fObjective]
copts = {
 CompilationTarget -> "WVM", 
 CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
};
gAux = Function[Evaluate[vars], Evaluate[fAux]];
cargs = {#, _Real} & /@ vars;
cobj = gAux @@ vars;
fComp = Compile[
  Evaluate@cargs,
  Evaluate@cobj,
  Evaluate[copts]
 ]
];
fObjective[args_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := fComp @@ args;

fcons = Join[{fObjective[vars]}, constraints];
NMinimize[fcons, init,Method -> "NelderMead"]
```

There were a couple of issues:

1. There were some syntax errors in your compile command. As a result, the compiled function was just an external call back to the math kernel. (Just slowing things down.)
2. Similar to the above, you need to tell `Compile` to inline the external definitions (otherwise it is just going to end up calling back to the Kernel).
3. Without specifying the `Method` to be use by `NMinimize`, Mathematica was wasting a lot of time using its default methods. (Which probably inlcude determing the gradient of the object function, which it would have to do numerically for the compiled case.)

As a final note: I used the "Wolfram Virtual Machine" as  target for the compile for two reasons. 1) It allows for greater debug easy using `CompiledFuntionTools` 2) The machine I am testing on did not have a "C" compiler installed. You should probably be able to gain more speed by switching the compilation target back to "C".

Comment: **0.** Thanks for taking the time **1.** Couldn't find syntax errors; did you mean the `Compile[{{args,_Real,1}},<...>]` instead of `Compile[{{x,_Real},...},<...>]`? **2.** I'm not sure but I think that `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` has to do with other *compiled* functions-probably irrelevant in this case **3.** This step probably helped the most as far as I can tell. (*Tested again with 48 vars and 100 obs specifying `Method` in all versions: Using `Function` halved the time consumed by function defined with `SetDelayed` and the compiled version (C or WVM) was almost 12x better!*)

Comment: 1. Yes there were a number of issues with how you specified your variables, inlcuding what you referred to. (But for example you were also using `x1_` etc in your argument specification, when Mathematica expects symbols.)
2. "InlineExternalDefinitions" does not have to with other compiled functions (that is "InlineCompiledFunctions"), but it is also not actually necessary in the final solution, because `cobj` does not refer to any other (non-built-in) functions.
PS. I've streamlined the answer a bit.